# Add comments block to Campaign detail view vtigerCRM

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I have recently enabled comments for the Campaign module, they work fine if you click comments on the right-hand menu, but I can't work out how to get the comments widget block to show within the detail view of the page.

I have added the following into the vtiger_links table which is meant to enable the comments widget block?

```
'108', '26', 'DETAILVIEWWIDGET', 'DetailViewBlockCommentWidget', 'block://ModComments:modules/ModComments/ModComments.php', '', '0', NULL, NULL, NULL
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You might to customize lot more with vtiger as Campaign module don't have Summary view support so it will not support any widgets first of all. So first try to get the summary view then you have to work for getting comment widget in page or might be you will get automatically after summary view works. I can't share all the changes as it requires many files changes.

I can give you a hint that enable summary view from

```
/modules/Campaigns/models/Module.php
```

Find isSummaryViewSupported function and set

```
return true;
```

to enable summary. But still you have to work more after this.